# How can I access a specific element's class name using useRef() to add/remove that class name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I have this jQuery snippet below

```
$("#navbarSupportedContent").on("click", "li", function (e) {
  $("#navbarSupportedContent ul li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

I'm trying to convert the above snippet into React.js code.  However, it's incorrect.  I can't even get passed the removing `active` class part, which's the first line in the above snippet.

```
const tabsNewAnimRef = useRef(null);
const horiSelectorRef = useRef(null);
const activeItemNewAnimRef = useRef(null);

tabsNewAnimRef.current.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let children = tabsNewAnimRef.current.children;

            // Convert an HTMLCollection to an Array
            let array = [...children];

            let childrenArray = array[0].children;
            console.log(childrenArray[2].classList[1].remove('active'));
});


<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" ref={tabsNewAnimRef}>
                <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <div className="hori-selector" ref={horiSelectorRef}>
                        <div className="left"></div>
                        <div className="right"></div>
                    </div>
                    <li className="nav-item" ref={activeItemNewAnimRef}>
                        <a className="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i className="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item active" ref={activeItemNewAnimRef}>
                        <a className="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i className="fas fa-house-user"></i>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item" ref={activeItemNewAnimRef}>
                        <a className="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i className="far fa-clone"></i>Components</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item" ref={activeItemNewAnimRef}>
                        <a className="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i className="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Calendar</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried looking up various possible ways to do this but I keep running into ealls.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't force jQuery or native JS DOM methods into React like that. You should really go back and look at the documentation on ["how to think in React"](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/thinking-in-react).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like useState would be appropriate for handling whether `active` is relevant or not. Something like this...

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

<div id="navbarSupportedContent" onClick={() => setActive(!active);}>
 <ul>
  <li className={active ? "active" : ""}>...</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I think you can probably get away without using useRef at all.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about using `useRef` - it won't do much good in this example. You need to be storing the active status of your list items in state.

In this example, to make things a little easier, there is a config array of objects that we initialise state with - all the items' active props are set to `false`. We can then use this array in state to build the list items in the JSX by `mapping` over each object and creating an element with the `nav-item` class as well as an active class if that prop has been updated in the state when an item is clicked.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Pass in the config
function List({ config }) {

  // Initialise state with it
  const [ items, setItems ] = useState(config);

  // When a list item is clicked we grab its `id`,
  // and create a new array of object by mapping over the
  // existing state. In the `map` callback we return an object
  // with an updated active prop depending on whether the id of the
  // object matches that id. Then we update the state with the new
  // array
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const reset = items.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        active: item.id === +id ? true : false
      };
    });
    setItems(reset);
  }

  // `map` over the items state, create a class using
  // `nav-item` and `active`, and then apply each item's
  // properties to the element. Finally add a click listener
  // to the element which calls the `handleClick` function.
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => {

        const cn = [
          'nav-item',
          item.active && 'active'
        ].join(' ');
                
        return (
          <li
            key={item.id}
            data-id={item.id}
            className={cn}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >{item.text}
          </li>
        );

      })}
    </ul>
  );

}

const config = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Dashboard', active: false },
  { id: 2, text: 'Home', active: false },
  { id: 3, text: 'Components', active: false },
  { id: 4, text: 'Calendar', active: false }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <List config={config} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; margin-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; }
.nav-item { padding: 0.25em; }
.nav-item:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.nav-item:not(.active):hover { background-color: #efefef; }
.active { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```